# Illegal invocation when accessing some properties of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

When I do

```
for (key in XMLHttpRequest.prototype) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

In the list of properties returned, I get `timeout`. In the same console, when I type

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.timeout
```

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Why?

How can I get assign the object referenced by timeout to another variable?

Answer (score 3):

`timeout` appears to be a getter that must be invoked on an actual XHR *instance*, not the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype`. There is no object referenced by it, and you cannot assign it to anything.

Comment: By XHR instance, do you mean an object that has `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` as its prototype?

Comment: Yes, but more specifically one that was initialised by a `new XMLHttpRequest` constructor call and possesses the necessary internal properties.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the getter on an instance created by `XMLHttpRequest`. It should already inherit from `XMLHttpRequest.prototype`, so the following will probably be enough:

```
instance.timeout
```

If for some reason you altered the [[Prototype]] chain of `instance`, or shadowed `timeout`, then you can call the getter manually:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, "timeout")
      .get.call(instance);
```

Or, since ES6,

```
Reflect.get(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, "timeout", instance);
```

Comment: Thank you! But why is it failing if not called from an instance? What in the code of `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.timeout` makes it uncallable if not on instance? And do you a link to where I could have found this information?

Comment: @Gradient [The spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-timeout-attribute). "The `timeout` attribute must return its value". Non-instances won't have an internal `timeout` value, so the `timeout` attribute getter will throw. This is formally specified in [WebIDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-attribute-getter)